# CakePHP Security::cipher decrypt not working

Tags: security, cakephp, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a hashed string using

```
Security::cipher($strHashedPassword, Configure::read('Security.salt'));
```

doesn't seem to be giving the desired result.  Does anyone have any experience with this? From the docs it looks like this should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that you **cannot decrypt a *hashed* string**. [Hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are irreversible by definition. They can't be *decrypted* because they're not *encrypted* to begin with, they're *hashed*. If you're really trying to decrypt a password hash (as produced by the AuthComponent?) you're out of luck.

`Security::cipher` can only decrypt strings that it encrypted as well, in which case you'd be talking about a *cipher text*, not a hash.

If you can demonstrate that this doesn't print "test":

```
$cipherText = Security::cipher('test', Configure::read('Security.salt'));
echo Security::cipher($cipherText, Configure::read('Security.salt'));
```

you have found a bug in Cake, most likely the one linked to by [@infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070987/cakephp-securitycipher-decrypt-not-working#4071011). Otherwise, you're trying something impossible.

Comment: but for me the below code is working...  , $c = Security::cipher('testing hash', Configure::read('Security.salt'));
$cc = Security::cipher($c, Configure::read('Security.salt'));
echo $cc;

Comment: @Vivek Exactly, as expected. Maybe you have misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: @-deceze  .  really confused.

Comment: @Vivek The question is about decrypting ***hashes*** using `Security::cipher`. The answer is that this is impossible and that `Security::cipher` only works the way you and I are showing.

Answer (score 2):

Hi have a look at CakePHP forum:

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/471-securitycipher-function-cannot-decrypt