# Cakephp manual login not initiating session

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm logging in a user using their fb user id. I therefore have no need for username or password when logging in a user. This works fine. However when I try to access `$this->Auth->user` nothing is saved. Please see code below.

```
$this->authUser = $this->User->findById($user_profile['id']);
        if($this->authUser){
            if($this->Auth->login($this->authUser)){
            $this->redirect('/Users/dash');
            }
```

Any ideas?

If I debug `$this->Auth` instead of doing the redirect I get the following:

```
object(AuthComponent) {
components => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Session',
    (int) 1 => 'RequestHandler'
)
authenticate => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Form'
)
authorize => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Controller'
)
ajaxLogin => null
flash => array(
    'element' => 'default',
    'key' => 'auth',
    'params' => array()
)
loginAction => array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'plugin' => null
)
loginRedirect => null
logoutRedirect => array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'plugin' => null
)
authError => 'You can't access that page'
allowedActions => array(
    (int) 0 => 'index',
    (int) 1 => 'view'
)
request => object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'index',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array(
        'signed_request' => 'Xyx9uGB4OZT_S59w-sMmJe5ofuzCwib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiJBQUFEcDlCdlpDMzRjQkFJSlBaQ3VwVGtoTlJRRGdIWkJEU0IxeWlTZDFhRTNLcXg1TzJma2Ewek1yOUlrTkVUZTBWbGNpaUxhMFpDUWFQd0ZOWVF3MnZyU1B4NXFrV2VqMjlOMzY4NXJ2d1pEWkQiLCJwYWdlIjp7ImlkIjoiMjQ3ODg2NjY1MzMxOTgwIiwibGlrZWQiOnRydW8BPoTx2YAtQtdin0.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzNDYyNjMyMDAsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM0NjI1NzU3NUsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfSwidXNlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiZ2IiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJlbl9HQiIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX0sInVzZXJfaWQiOiI2NjEyNjMzODgifQ'
    )
    query => array()
    url => 'Users/index'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/Users/index'
}
response => object(CakeResponse) {

}
settings => array(
    'authError' => 'You can't access that page',
    'authorize' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Controller'
    )
)
Session => object(SessionComponent) {
    settings => array()
    components => array()
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: I'm very interested on this particular question since I just had the same problem trying to manually log in a default user. In my case I had to resort to assigning the login data to `$this->request->data` and calling `$this-Auth->login()` but that isn't feasible if you don't have an unencrypted password. Calling `$this->Auth->login($data)` always returned true but never started the session. (cakephp 2.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (works for me, i'm using it to auto-login a user after account activation):

```
$user = $this->User->findById($id);
$user = $user['User'];
$this->Auth->login($user);
```

Also $this->Auth->user is not a property. If you want to access it, you have to write `$this->Auth->user();`.

Comment: I was using a multi-demensional array and I only realised after seeing ` $user['User'];` in your post. Thanks @nahri

Answer (score 0):

You were not able to login because the find result contain the hashed password. And `$this->Auth->login()` method will again converting it into hashed password. [You can't decrypt the hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070987/cakephp-securitycipher-decrypt-not-working).

You can do it so using the following code:

```
        if($this->Auth->login($user_profile['id'])){
        $this->redirect('/users/dash');
        }
```

Auth::login accepts either a username/password combination or simply a user id (the primary key of the user model in the database).

Comment: I tried this with no success. I changed the redirect to debug $this->Auth and no user data is stored.

Comment: This worked absolutely fine. check `$user_profile['id'] corresponds to user_id in users table or not.` What it looks, you are not providing `user_id` in the login method. Kindly confirm at your end. Thanks.